# Regular Expression - split line into more with prefix in string

Tags: regex, sed, multiline

I am trying to use sed to get this string:

```
1234    dog, hat, cat
```

into this multi-line string:

```
1234 dog
1234 hat
1234 cat
```

It is just about replacing the comma by a new-line but putting the numbers after each new line. I am trying to do this with a sed command. My problem is that I want to catch the numbers and do a backreference but without affecting the simple comma matching. I read about \K but I am lost. Can anyone find me a sed -E command that accomplishes this?

Comment: I was trying this without success:
sed -E 's/(\d)?\K?,/\n\1/g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed does not know \d and such. You need to use `[0-9], \{0,1\}, \+`...
also if you may have different number of "words" then awk is much better with for, as it was suggested.

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)[\ \t]\+\([^,]\+\),[\ \t]\+\([^,]\+\),[\ \t]\+\([^,]\+\)/\1 \2\n\1 \3\n\1 \4\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, zolo. This looks complicated and it shows me that this problem cannot be solved with sed alone. Especially if the comma elements vary. We need control structures. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is easier done using `awk`:

```
s='1234    dog, hat, cat'

awk -F '[, ]+' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' <<< "$s"
1234 dog
1234 hat
1234 cat
```

Comment: Thank you, anubhava. Yes, with program logic it is not so hard. I was not sure if that can be solved with regular expression power. Thank you for that awk example.

Comment: `awk` is indeed the best solution for this problem. Provided `sed` solution can break for many cases. If this answer worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/ +/ /g;/\n/!s/^((\S+)\s*[^,]*),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Reduce multiple sets of spaces to one each. If the line does not contain any newlines, replace each `,` by a newline followed by the key, print, delete and repeat.